# Automating the generation of multiple plots in R using Python

Tags: python, r, shell, automation

I have a folder full of .txt files that I use to generate manhattan and Q-Q plots. I have to write the script for each one, and it's tedious. I know there must be a better way, maybe with Python?. Here is what I am repeating:

```
> 
> cd /Home/*User*/Path/Path
> qsub -I
> R
> TARC_FVII_man_MAF5<-read.table ("TARC_man_FULL_Factor_VII_MAF5_20140102.txt", header=T)
> source("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/66281/0_Permanent/qqman.r")
> pdf("Tarc_FVII_man_MAF5.pdf")
> manhattan(TARC_FVII_man_MAF5)
> dev.off()
```

So basically, I am navigating to the .txt files, requesting an interactive node on the cluster, opening R, loading the file into an R dataset, loading some code from a dropbox file (I'm assuming this is what allows R to make the plots, but I'm not clear on it), telling R to make a pdf, putting a manhattan plot into the pdf, and then turning off, or saving the pdf.

What I'd like to do is figure out a python script to go into this folder with the multiple .txt files, and use R to make manhattan plots for all of them. Firstly, is this feasible, and if so, how could I begin to go about it?

Comment: why do you need python?

Comment: The `dir()` aka `list.files()` function takes regular expressions, and is vectorised.  Use it to get a vector of files, then process it.  Can be a three-liner.